# authorize.net payment gateway no longer supports the requested method of integration

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am using authorize.net Payment Form in my website. But I am getting error every-time. Please check here -

```
<form action="https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="post">
<!--<form method="post" action="https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll"> -->

<input type="hidden" id="x_receipt_link_url" name="x_receipt_link_url" value="http://oursite.com/print.php">
<input type="hidden" id="x_cancel_url" name="x_cancel_url" value="http://oursite.com/cancel.php">

<input type="hidden" name="x_login" value="6q9wmLrD34Fe">
<input type="hidden" id="x_type" name="x_type" value="AUTH_CAPTURE">
<input type="hidden" id="x_version" name="x_version" value="3.1">
<input type="hidden" id="x_show_form" name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM">
<input type="hidden" id="x_relay_always" name="x_relay_always" value="false">
<input type="hidden" id="x_delim_data" name="x_delim_data" value="TRUE">
<input type="hidden" id="x_receipt_link_method" name="x_receipt_link_method" value="LINK">
<input type="hidden" id="x_invoice_num" name="x_invoice_num" value="CART-36">
<input type="hidden" id="x_amount" name="x_amount" value="250.00">
<input type="submit" id="checkout-submit" value="Pay Now">
</form>
```

My tested link is - 
http://dev.raddyx.in/login-oauth/authorize.html

Please check and let me know where is the error coming.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing either a transaction key if you want to use the [Authorize.Net API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions), or a fingerprint if you are attempting to invoke a [hosted payment form](http://www.authorize.net/support/SIM_guide.pdf).